# Oracle: Using an array datav type in package

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a package which contains a procedure in which I need to query a list of id numbers, which are varchar2. I will have to query this same list multiple times, and I'd rather not have redo the query. Ideally I'd like to make a function in my package that would return the list of id numbers. So I could load the array of id numbers into a variable, and then use that variable as a table throughout my procedure. I've been googling like crazy and it just doesn't seem like it's possible. Is there some way to do this?

Note: I'm not able to create a new type at the schema level, and it won't let me do this with a local collection type.

Also, I would prefer not to use dynamic sql; the main query in my procedure is enormous, and I don't want to deal with a string of that size.

I want to do something like this:

```
id_number_list array_type := my_function();

select *
from my_table mt
left join table(id_number_list) idl on mt.id_number = idl.column_value;
```

EDIT: Thanks for your help so far! MTO's answer works for a select statement join, like I described above. However, I also need to delete from the table where the id_number is in the list. This gives me an "invalid data type" error. What could explain this? The data type should always be the same: varchar2(10).

Here I create the type at package level:

```
type string_list is table of varchar2(10);
```

Then I create a function that returns the list of id numbers (for our purposes, the "action" is always c_action_refresh, so the if statement is true):

```
  function get_modified_ids(scope in smallint, action in smallint) return string_list is
    
  modified_ids string_list := string_list();
  last_refreshed date;
  
  begin
   
  last_refreshed := get_last_refreshed_date(scope,action);
  
  if action = c_action_refresh then
   
   select id_number
   bulk collect into modified_ids
   from(
  
          select id_number
          from adv.hr_giving cg
          join adv.pbi_dates d
            on d.DATE_FULL = trunc(cg.processed_date)
         where d.RELATIVE_DATE >= last_refreshed
           and d.RELATIVE_DATE <= trunc(CURRENT_DATE)
           and cg.fiscal_year >= adv.current_fiscal_year - 6
        
        union
        
        select gi.gift_donor_id as id_number
          from adv.gift gi
         where gi.date_added >= last_refreshed
            or gi.date_modified >= last_refreshed
        
        union
        
        select p.pledge_donor_id as id_number
          from adv.pledge_rev p
         where p.date_added >= last_refreshed
            or p.date_modified >= last_refreshed
        
        union
        
        select a.id_number
          from adv.affiliation a
         where a.date_added >= last_refreshed
            or a.date_modified >= last_refreshed
    );
    
  end if;
  
  return(modified_ids);
  
  end get_modified_ids;
```

Then, in my procedure, I initialize a variable by calling the function:

```
modified_ids string_list := get_modified_ids(scope,action);
```

Then I try to use the list in a delete statement:

```
  delete from advrpt.pbi_gvg_profile_ag p
  where p.id_number in
        (select column_value from table(modified_ids));
```

This gives the error ORA-00902: invalid datatype. The type of id_number is varchar2(10). And again, it works fine in a join in a select statement.

So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a variable in the package (as there would only be a single variable and if your procedure is called twice in short succession then the second set of values would overwrite the first and potentially cause issues if that happened mid-way through processing the first invocation).

Instead, create a user-defined collection type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

And pass a collection as an argument to the procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE your_procedure (
  i_numbers IN  number_list,
  o_cursor1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_cursor2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor1 FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   your_table
    WHERE  id MEMBER OF i_numbers;

  OPEN o_cursor2 FOR
    SELECT y.*
    FROM   your_table y
           INNER JOIN TABLE(i_numbers) n
           ON (y.id = n.COLUMN_VALUE);
END;
/
```

Then call it using, for example:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur1  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_cur2  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_id    your_table.id%TYPE;
  v_value your_table.value%TYPE;
BEGIN
  your_procedure(number_list(1,5,13), v_cur1, v_cur2);
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur1 INTO v_id, v_value;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur1%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id || ', ' || v_value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

Or create the type as part of your package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE your_package AS
  TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE your_procedure (
    i_numbers IN  number_list,
    o_cursor1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    o_cursor2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  );
END;
/
```

Then create the package body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY your_package AS
  PROCEDURE your_procedure (
    i_numbers IN  number_list,
    o_cursor1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    o_cursor2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN o_cursor1 FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM   your_table
      WHERE  id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(i_numbers));

    OPEN o_cursor2 FOR
      SELECT y.*
      FROM   your_table y
             INNER JOIN TABLE(i_numbers) n
             ON (y.id = n.COLUMN_VALUE);
  END;
END;
/
```

*Note: The `MEMBER OF` operator only works with collections defined in the SQL scope and not collections defined locally in a PL/SQL scope.*

Then call it using, for example:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur1  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_cur2  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_id    your_table.id%TYPE;
  v_value your_table.value%TYPE;
BEGIN
  your_package.your_procedure(your_package.number_list(1,5,13), v_cur1, v_cur2);
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur1 INTO v_id, v_value;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur1%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id || ', ' || v_value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cnTK-xsC)

Comment: Thanks! If I define the type at the package level, it will let me use it with the table() expression? I know that if I create the type at the procedure level, it gives me an error about not being able to use local collection types in this way.

Comment: @JamesHarpe The fiddle linked in the answer shows it working with a package-defined collection.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks as if you have it all. If not, here's an example.

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return sys.odcinumberlist(10, 20);
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.
```

How to use it?

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    id_number_list  sys.odcinumberlist := f_test;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select e.deptno, e.ename
  5                  from emp e join table(id_number_list) idl on idl.column_value = e.deptno
  6                  order by 1, 2
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.deptno ||' '|| cur_r.ename);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
10 CLARK
10 KING
10 MILLER
20 ADAMS
20 FORD
20 JONES
20 SCOTT
20 SMITH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```